# reading selected column from a AWS S3 parquet file

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, parquet

I am reading parquet files/objects from AWS S3 using boto3 SDK.   the parquet object can have many fields (columns) that I don't need to read.   Assume the parquet object has 10 fields

```
A B C D E F G H I J
```

Is there a way to read just get just columns A E and H.  I am currently reading the parquet obj using an s3client as below.

```
obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), **args)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, I never noticed this. Pandas and its backend parquet engines can read from s3 directly using fsspec/s3fs, and only fetch the bytes you need for the columns you specify:

```
df = pd.read_parquet(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}", columns=["A", "E", "H"])
```

You may need to specify extra `storage_options={...}` if you need to give credentials for s3.